# How to get the retrieve next line in Python whe reading from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text-files, file-management

I have a text file that resembles like this which is read from a server:

```
Jo's Deli Express
Potatoes
30
Fish
20
Chicken Meat
15

Margo's Grocery
Beans
20
Carrots
15
Apples
30
```

The two shops are separated by an empty line so that we can calculate values for each store.

I want to calculate the total revenue of products(the numbers beneath the product * value for a single item) of these shops and the number of items that were bought in total.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to link the name of the items to the values below it. So Python needs to know that as it is reading each line it should know what value to multiply the number beneath it. For example a potato costs 0.70 for one piece so it should multiply 0.7 by 30 and so on for the different items.

This is what I have coded so far:

```
user = input("Enter file name - AprilSales, MaySales, or JuneSales")
revenue = 0
response = None

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("link of server" + user + ".txt")
except:
    print("File not found")

fileData = response.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(fileData)):
    fileData[i] = fileData[i].decode('utf-8')

for line in fileData:
     if len(line) != 0:
         #try block to only convert the strings which are able to be converted to ints and leave the rest
         try: 
              print(int(line))
         except:
              print(line)
              if(line == "Potatoes"):
                  revenue = revenue + int(line.next() * 0.7)
              if(line == "Fish"):
                  revenue = revenue + int(line.next() * 1.50)
              if(line == "Chicken"):
                  revenue = revenue + int(line.next() * 1.70)
      else:
        break
```

Comment: is the item of the shop always 3? or it can be many?

Comment: @VLDCNDN no it can be many

Answer (score 0):

we can use the itertools module to help us process the file, given that they are separated by a black line like so

```
>>> import itertools
>>> text="""Jo's Deli Express
Potatoes
30
Fish
20
Chicken Meat
15

Margo's Grocery
Beans
20
Carrots
15
Apples
30"""
>>> for key,group in itertools.groupby(map(str.strip,text.splitlines()), bool):
        print(key, list(group))

    
True ["Jo's Deli Express", 'Potatoes', '30', 'Fish', '20', 'Chicken Meat', '15']
False ['']
True ["Margo's Grocery", 'Beans', '20', 'Carrots', '15', 'Apples', '30']

>>>
```

first we get the lines, we strip each one (to make sure that the empty line is really empty and doesn't have some sneaky space there, and remove unnecessary white space from the others one too, and to make that into a one liner we can use a [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)), then use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to split that on the on black line.

Now we just need to process each of those groups, given that the structure is now [store_name, produc1,amount1, produc2,amount2, ..., producn,amountn] we just need to build a convenient way to handle that, and pack that into a function.

But first let make a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) with all those prices to have them all in neat little place and get rip off an endless if-else cascade

```
prices = {"Potatoes": 0.7,
          "Fish":1.50,
          "Chicken":1.70,
          "Beans": 2, 
          "Carrots": 1.5, 
          "Apples": 3,
          ...
         }
```

now lets build that function

```
def process_data(data):
    name, *products_data = data
    it = iter(products_data)
    revenue = 0
    products={}
    for prod, amount in zip(it, it):
        amount = int(amount)
        revenue += prices.get(prod,0) * amount #by using the .get method we avoid getting a KeyError exception
        products[prod] = products.get(prod,0) + amount #and in case of a repeat we wouldn't overwrite it
    return name, revenue, products
```

now we can feed the groups we get above to this function

```
>>> for key,group in itertools.groupby(map(str.strip,text.splitlines()), bool):
        if not key:
            continue
        print(process_data(group))

    
("Jo's Deli Express", 51.0, {'Potatoes': 30, 'Fish': 20, 'Chicken Meat': 15})
("Margo's Grocery", 152.5, {'Beans': 20, 'Carrots': 15, 'Apples': 30})
>>>
```

and now in turn you can you can save it in another data structure like a dictionary yet again

```
>>> stores_data={}
>>> for key,group in itertools.groupby(map(str.strip,text.splitlines()), bool):
        if not key:
            continue
        store,revenue,prod = process_data(group)
        stores_data[store]={"revenue": revenue, "products":prod}
 
        
>>> stores_data
{"Jo's Deli Express": {'products': {'Chicken Meat': 15,
                                    'Fish': 20,
                                    'Potatoes': 30},
                       'revenue': 51.0},
 "Margo's Grocery": {'products': {'Apples': 30, 'Beans': 20, 'Carrots': 15},
                     'revenue': 152.5}}
>>>
```

Now that everything is packed and processed, asking for the global revenue is simple

```
>>> sum(x["revenue"] for x in stores_data.values())
203.5
>>>
```

to know how many items in total a particular store sold

```
>>> for store, data in store_data.items():
        print(store, sum(data["products"].values()))

    
Jo's Deli Express 65
Margo's Grocery 65
>>>
```

---

the `it = iter(products)` , `zip(it, it)` have the following effect:

```
>>> a=range(10)
>>> it=iter(a)
>>> list(zip(it,it))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
>>>
```

`iter` make an iterator of the thing, that is a one time only iterable of the thing

```
>>> it=iter(a)
>>> list(it)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(it)
[]
>>>
```

which we want so when zip consume it wouldn't hit the same element again making it possible to pair it with the next one, if that weren't the case we would get

```
>>> list(zip(a,a))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
>>>
```

---

You can replace the `products` dict in process_data for a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) so you don't need to use .get method, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader